# Why does having an iPv6-only contract with my ISP could affect online gaming?

Tags: ipv4, ipv6

What is the reason some Online Games nay not work properly when one's ISP provide IPv6 only?

Some ISPs offer IPv4 at an extra cost. Are there alternatives to this to solve the gaming related problems, i.e. making your console look like it has a IPv4 address through other means (possibily involving extra harware like another router or a home server).

NOTE: I get glimpses of this info by googling, but I am finding it hard to find an article that explains where this problem comes from.

CONTEXT: I am having issues playing online on a Nintendo Switch. The console reports "NAT D" (a bad rating) even while I make it an "Exposed Host" with my router. I suspect this is really not a NAT problem, so I am trying to understand the IPv4/IPv6 issue.

Comment: Your question should be on topic on [su] - however, to get a "real" IPv4 address you either need to tunnel to a tunnel/VPN provider (introducing yet additional latency) or change your contract: change ISPs or pay for IPv4. You can't outwit physics.

Comment: @Zac67 Thanks again. I flagged my question for migration to Super User. Latency I am not worried about (moderate) latency for now... I am trying to play something that is not fast-paced. Of course I do not know if my game/console actively measures latency and might punish me for that...

Answer (score 3):

"IPv6 only" usually means [DS-Lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=DS-Lite) with carrier-grade NAT (CGNAT): your ISP provides you with a public IPv6 prefix and a *private* IPv4 address, often from the 192.0.0.0/29 subnet. An IPv4 connection is tunneled across v6 to your ISP's CGNAT cascade where it's source NATed to a (shared) public IPv4. This scheme saves public IP addresses because customers share fewer addresses than would be required with a 1:1 scheme.

This means that all your IPv4 connections are source NATed without any control of yours. There's no way you can allow incoming connections ("open port", "port forward", "reverse NAT", etc).

Basically, there are two possible solutions.

1. Pay for a public IPv4 address or change ISPs.
2. Find a tunnel provider who allows you to tunnel or VPN to a public IPv4 address that you can control. You could then set up port forwarding through the tunnel. Depending on the provider and your equipment, the setup can be quite challenging. Also, the tunnel lengthens your Internet connection and thus increases latency - for latency-sensitive applications (games, VoIP, ...) that increase might push your connection over the acceptable limit.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer... this is helping me a lot to understand this problem. Do you know why DS-Lite could affect online gaming on consoles? (I do not know if the Nintendo Switch is the only hardware with this problem). Maybe I should ask a new question for this.

Comment: This answer wouldn't be specific to online gaming on consoles.  It would affect all IPv4 communication over the Internet (including online gaming on consoles).  When you make outgoing communication, your communication gets translated ("NAT") and placed in a chart/table.  When a device on the Internet wishes to communicate with your (console) device, the remote end sends traffic to the ISP's public address.  Then the ISP needs to use the incoming port number to check the chart/table, and figure out which IPv6 address to use for an IPv6 communication to reach you. This takes time, so it slows.

Comment: @TOOGAM NAT is used for IPv4, not for IPv6. Apparently, the "application" server doesn't support v6 which started this whole problem.